# Change the MTU or Packet Size for Bluetooth in Android?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

How can I change the MTU or Packet Size for Bluetooth in Android?! It is not possible in using Android's API, right? I believe I should change the native codes. How can I change it? And is it also possible to change the transmission rate, or it is hardware dependent?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, You are right - it is not possible in Android API. You can only get MTU value for an interface with networkInterface.getMTU() method.

Based on sources for the NetworkInterface class

```
public int getMTU() throws SocketException {
    return readIntFile("/sys/class/net/" + name + "/mtu");
}
```

You probably can change MTU value (for rooted devices) - You need to write new int MTU value to "/sys/class/net/" + networkInterface.getName() + "/mtu" file.

But I'm not sure if it is reliable solution for You.

Comment: ummm, so it seems the MTU size is predefined on the device; interesting! For each interface it's different, right? WiFi, BT

Comment: Yes, seems like that - default MTU value depends on interface type

Comment: With Android API >=21 you should be able to change that